# DataGrid WPF при растягивании столбца не изменяется размер заголовка

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

[image: Пример окна]

```
  <DataGrid Name="dgLokasi" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Loaded="dgLokasi_Loaded">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <!--<DataGridTextColumn
                    x:Name="DSColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=DS}"
                    Header="DS" Width="80" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn
                    x:Name="StyleColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Style}"
                    Header="Style" Width="80" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn
                    x:Name="ColorColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Color}"
                    Header="Color" Width="80" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn
                    x:Name="LotColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Lot}"
                    Header="Lot" Width="80" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn
                    x:Name="SizeColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Size}"
                    Header="Size" Width="80" IsReadOnly="True"/>-->

            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">                            
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" Text="Оборудование"></TextBlock></Grid>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>                        
                    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>                                
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Text="Янвраь" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="Gray" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Кол" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="ТО " Margin="0,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="Вр" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=col1}" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=To1}"  Margin="0,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=Time1}"  Margin="0,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>                


        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте стиль, который растянет контент по горизонтали:

```
            ...
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <!--Начало фрагмента-->
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <!--Конец фрагмента-->
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                   ...
```